# How to run mapreduce jar using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, maven-2, mapreduce

I am trying to use eclipse (Kepler) for building, running MapReduce (ver 2), using maven plugin.

I am able to successfully build the project, and i see that maven created jar file as final output, suppose that jar is -> mapreducedemo.jar.

Now, my question is how to run this jar using eclipse?

I tried it on command prompt and it works fine, like this:

```
--> $ hadoop jar mapreducedemo.jar MainDriver input output.
```

The thing is hadoop is shell script and it sets all the env  variables internally, and required jars.

How can we run this mapreducedemo.jar using eclipse?

Any answers would be great help.

Thanks,
Vipin

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just run MainDriver as a java application from within Eclipse.  Maven will make sure you have all your dependencies and MainDriver, once it configures the job will submit it for execution, just as it does when you run the hadoop jar command.

Comment: Thanks so much for your info, and thanks for your follow up. I am going to give one more try and see if this works out, if not then would share the info, and it would be kind if you can share info. Thanks a lot, at the same time, i want to make sure that i have done my part of homework before i ask further help. Really appreciate your follow up, thanks ton!